# Doctrine - count records from different tables

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

i want to fetch the count from three different table which is not related. for which i am using this SQL query.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM user) AS userCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM item) AS itemCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM sub_category) as categoryCount;
```

Is it possible to use DQL for the above query? or do i have to use rawSQL query?

I am using doctrine 1.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around i found the solution by myself. i.e by directly using the pdo connection instance.

```
$q = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$result = $q->execute(' SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM user) AS userCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM item) AS itemCount, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM sub_category) as categoryCount;'
);
$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

while this works for me as of now. i was still wondering if it was possible to convert it into DQL. i tried different syntaxes and approaches like Doctrine's RAW SQL but couldn't get it to work.